# How can you achieve this style of layout using Bootstrap but then move to a different arrangement on desktops?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to recreate this type of view for a list of 'offers' as groupons have when you visit the site on mobile:

[image]

As we can see they seem to be using a new unordered list item for each offer box, and then the offer itself is contained within a single list item, which has a link, image, header, and a table for the details about the bottom. This looks good and seems to work nicely.

I want to recreate this using bootstrap - in such a way that when I then view the layout on my desktop, the site scales up and perhaps new fields / details which were not visible in the example above suddenly become visible.

Answer (score 0):

here, they are using tables. But, It is the old way, you can redesign itself with bootstrap. The only thing you should know is bootstrap. 
they have a great documentation of their classes and what they do. 
for example:- if you need an element to disappear in mobiles and appear in tabs and machines, you can use .sm-hidden class.

Give it a try.